# Using lambda to create a new variable in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

if I want to do the following in Pandas, how do I do it using Lambda:

```
df['c'] = 0
df['c'][(df['a']==1) | (df['b'] ==1)] = 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can't justify using a `lambda`

```
df.assign(c=df[['a', 'b']].eq(1).any(1).astype(int))
```

But if you insist:

```
df.assign(c=lambda d: d[['a', 'b']].eq(1).any(1).astype(int))
```

Comment: I was used to doing the following (create a two category c variable  based on another variable): 

 `df['c'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: 0 if x>5 else 1)`

can I do something similar using one variable?

Comment: Yes but I wouldn’t advise it

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply but change the axis.

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[1,2]})
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda df: 1 if(df['a'] == 1| df['b']==1) else 0, axis = 1)
```